# Bring Rails asset pipeline to any project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, sprockets

Is it possible to bring the asset pipeline standalone to any project? I wrote an entire standlone client in CoffeeScript using the Rails asset pipeline (so it would automagically bundle my Coffee and SASS and I could have a nice directory structure), but am now trying to figure out how to best move all that JavaScript/CSS to a different non-Rails project.

Comment: What client do you intend to use? Maybe try [**sinatra-assetpack**](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack)

Answer (score 0):

The asset pipeline is based off of [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets). So your first step would probably be to check out that gem. Sorry if that's a little vague, but I hope that helps out.